# Hash X509 certificate with SHA 256 in c#

Tags: c#, hash, certificate, sha256, bank

I work on an EBICS implementation in C# and I need to send to my bank the hash of my three certificates in **SHA256 format** in order to enable EBICS link with it.

I generated them in C# with BouncyCastle and now I have a `X509Certificate2` object.

So to hash my certificate I used the following code :

```
String HashCertificate = Certificat.GetCertHashString();
```

And he return me the following result :

> 21952A5F79CA3232A656794EE4532BECF5AE3960

But the length don't match with the lenght of the hash of the bank certificate :

> 57436AD3D09989ED74F4FCCDBF7668C43F8BF87C933F90B065ED442A22E5B0BF

So I think the `GetCertHashString()` function return the hash of the certificate in **SHA1** format and I have no idea how I can hash it in **SHA256**.

Can you help me please ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getcerthashstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) GetCertHashString method always

> Returns the SHA1 hash value for the X.509v3 certificate as a hexadecimal string.

regardless of signature algorithm since it is Windows specific thumbprint used internally in certifcates store.

You can calculate any other hash by accessing certificate content from its `RawData` property, e.g. for SHA256:

```
using (var hasher = SHA256.Create())
{
    var hash = hasher.ComputeHash(cert.RawData);
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(hash));
}
```